# My backend response isn't functioning the way I want it to

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm creating a forum website and in the page where you sign in your username and password, I'm trying to send a response in the backend to the console.log in the front end but they keep returning "undefined" or the response 'Incorrect Login' even if the Username and Password is correct.

I checked if I misspelt the data names in the backend and database and they're both correct so I still don't understand what I'm doing wrong

here are some of my code

signIn.js

```
import apiClient from '../../api/apiclient'
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function SignIn() {
   
    const [username, getUser] = useState ('')
    const [password, getPass] = useState ('')
    
    const onSubmit = (event) => {
     event.preventDefault()
      apiClient.signIn(username, password).then( (response) => {
        console.log(response)
      });
      
      
    }
    
       
         return (
           <section class="index-banner">
             <div>Sign In</div>
             <div>
                 <label>username</label> 
                 <input  type="text" id="username" onChange = {e => {getUser(e.target.value)}}></input> 
               </div>
               <div>   
                 <label>password</label>
                 <input type="text" id="password" onChange = {e => {getPass(e.target.value)}}></input>
               </div>  
               <div>
                 <button onClick={onSubmit}>Sign In</button>
               </div> 
               <div>
                   <button>Create Account</button>
               </div>     
           </section>         
         )      
       
       
     }
     export default SignIn;
```

apiClient.js

```
import axios from 'axios'
//communicates with the Backend
export default class apiClient {
    static signUp(user, pass){
    console.log (user)
    console.log (pass)
   
    axios
    .post('http://localhost:8080/signUp', {
        username: user,
        password: pass,
    })
    
    .then (res => {
        return res.data;
    })
    .catch (error => {
        console.error();
    })
    
    }

    static signIn(user, pass){
    
    axios
    .get('http://localhost:8080/signIn', {
        username: user,
        password: pass,
    })   
    .then (res => {
        console.log (res.data)
        return res.data;
    })
    .catch (error => {
        return error();
    })
    
         
    }

    static forum(comm){        
    console.log (comm);
    axios
    .post('http://localhost:8080/forum', {
        comment: comm,
    })    
    .then (res => {
        return res.data;
    })
    .catch (error => {
        console.error();
    })
        
    }

    static getting(ipt){
        console.log (ipt);
        axios
        .get('http://localhost:8080/forum', {
            input: ipt,
        })
        .then (res => {
            return res.data;
        })
        .catch (error => {
            console.error();
        })    
    }
    
}
```

backend.js

```
const express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var app = express()

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())
const mysql = require('mysql')
var cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors())

const port = 8080

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "Steven1spielberg",
  port: "3306",
  database: "forum"
})

app.post('/signUp', function (req, res) {
    const queryString = "INSERT INTO accounts (Username, Password) VALUES (?, ?)"
    console.log (req.body)
    con.query(queryString, [req.body.username, req.body.password], function (err, result){
    if (err) {
      throw err
    }
    if (result.length != 1) {
    return res.send('Failed to Add');
  } else {
    res.send("Account Created");
  }
    })
  })

app.get('/signIn', function (req, res){
  const queryString = 'SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE Username = ? AND Password = ?'
    con.query(queryString, [req.body.username, req.body.password], function (err, result){

    if (err) {
     throw err;
    }
    if (result.length != 1) {
      return  res.send('Incorrect Login')
    }
   else {
     res.send("Logged in")
    }
    });  
});

app.post('/forum', function (req, res){
  const queryString = "INSERT INTO comments (Comments) VALUES (?)"
  console.log (req.body)
  con.query(queryString, [req.body.comment], function (err, result){
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    if (result.length != 1) {
      return res.send('Comment failed to post')
    }
   else {
     res.send("Posted Comment")
    };
    })
})
app.get('/forum', function (req, res){
  const queryString = 'SELECT * FROM comments WHERE Comments = ?'
  console.log (req.body)
  con.query(queryString, [req.body.insert], function (err, result){
    if (err) {throw err;}
    var commenting = JSON.stringify(result)
    res.send(commenting);
    console.log (commenting)
  }) 
})
app.listen(port, (  ) => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

Comment: You really need to strip this down to a minimal reproduction case. Just doing a code dump of your entire express/react app is probably more than most people are willing to dig through. In addition to that, are you seeing any errors in the terminal? What about the JS console? What about the network inspector?

Comment: every *api-point* besides `.get('/forum', ...)` is missing a call to `res.send` with the data returned from your `con.query`; you are only setting the result when there is an error, you need to do it when the call is successful too.

Comment: Can you make sure that the `req.body.username` and `req.body.password` are being correctly passed to your "signIn" request? If your code is throwing the 'Incorrect Login' error then it is either not finding an entry in your database with the username and password you are using or it is finding more than one. Debug this part, make sure you are passing the right data and make sure you actually have only one entry with that data in your database.